# Updating background color of JTextField automatically

Tags: java, swing, background, jtextfield

well i made a JTextField and i want it's background to be red when there are no characters in it, and once a character is written to be automatically changed to green.

i tried this code

```
textField1.setBackground(textField1.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("") ? Color.RED : Color.GREEN);
```

but it doesn't automatically update it.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should add documentListener

```
textfield.getDocument().addDocumentListener(this);

@Override
    public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) 
    {
        textField1.setBackground(textField1.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("") ? Color.RED : Color.GREEN);
    }

    @Override
    public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) 
    {
        textField1.setBackground(textField1.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("") ? Color.RED : Color.GREEN);
    }

    @Override
    public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) 
    {
        textField1.setBackground(textField1.getText().equalsIgnoreCase("") ? Color.RED : Color.GREEN);    
    }
```

Also try setting the opaque property of the Textfield.

```
textField1.setOpaque(True)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 import java.awt.*;
 import javax.swing.*;
class m extends  JFrame
{
JTextField t;
public m()
{
    setVisible(true);
    setSize(1000,1000);
    setLayout(null);
    t =new JTextField();
    t.setBounds(100,100,100,100);
    add(t);
    Timer t1=new Timer(100,new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
        {
        if(t.getText().equals(""))
        {
            t.setBackground(Color.red);
        }
        else
            { 
        t.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        }

        }
            }
        );
        t1.start();

}

public static void main (String[] args) {
    new m();
    }
  }
```

[image]
 Before Insert Text in JtextField

[image]
After inserting Text in JTextField